# How to best implement a global socket using a service to send and receive messages from it?

Tags: android, sockets

I need to have a open connection with a server and I want to use the same Socket in different activities so probably a Service would be the best solution. I thought of these possibilities:

- using an IntentService and send broadcasts back to activities - but I don't know what happens with the state of the socket when the service gets "Stopped" (IntentService stops itself after running last onHandleIntent - from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent)).
- using an IntentService with a singleton where I hold the socket - don't know how viable this is.
- an AIDL Service or BoundService with a Messenger - I'm not really sure what problems can occur here.

I'm mostly interested in the best way to do this, so if you have a better suggestion please do tell :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would do things like This.
1. Create a class dedicated for networking,

public class NetworkProxy {

```
private static NetworkProxy sInstance;

public static NetworkProxy getInstance() {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new NetworkProxy();
    }
    return sInstance;
}

public void connect() {
    // to be done
}

public void disconnect() {
    // to be done
}

public void transact() {
    // network communications goes here
}
```

}

Every time an arbitrary Activity needs to interact with server. just call NetworkProxy.getInstance().transact();

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way to do this is using service with threads.